# Passing data between several components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I've got this view of animal cards called like this:

```
    <AnimalsCard {...elephant}/>
    <AnimalsCard {...hippo}/>
    <AnimalsCard {...sugar_glider}/>
```

[image: View]

My AnimalCard code looks like this:

```
export const AnimalsCard = ({ id, animal, img }) => {
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    return (
        <>
                <CardContainer id={id} img={img}>
                <CardContent>
                    <CardTitle>{animal}</CardTitle>
                    <CardButton to={`${id}`}>Dowiedz się więcej</CardButton>
                    </CardContent>
                </CardContainer>

        </>
    )
};
```

And my animal objects look like that:

```
export const elephant = {
    animal: 'Słoń indyjski',
    id: 'slon_indyjski',
    species: 'mammals',
    img: require('../../../images/animals/mammals/elephant.jpg'),
    occurance: '',
    habitat: '',
    diet: '',
    reproduction: '',
    conservationStatus: '',
    funFactOne: ''
}
```

When I click the button, new page of the animal id opens up:

```
        <Route path="/:id" component={AnimalsDetails} />
```

On AnimalsDetails page, I would like to display all of the animal object data. I unfortunately have no idea how to pass it because I'm a beginner and hardly know anything about props and stuff.
My current approach is that in the AnimalsDetails I retrieve the ID using useParams();

```
export const AnimalsDetails = () => {
    const [mammal, setMammal] = useState(null);
    let { id } = useParams();
    
useEffect(() => {
        const mammal = mammalsData.filter(thisMammal => thisMammal.id === id);
        setMammal(mammal);
        // console.log(mammal[0].animal);
     }, [id]);

 return ( <AnimalsDetailsContainer>
                {/* <div>{mammal[0].id}</div> */}
            </AnimalsDetailsContainer>
    )
};

export default AnimalsDetails;
```

And then using the ID from URL, I'm filtering my mammalsData array that I've created only to test if the approach works (I wish I could use the previously created objects but I don't know if it's possible). It looks like that:

```
export const mammalsData = [
    {

    [...]

},

{
    animal: 'abc',
    id: 'fgh',
    species: 'idontknow',
    img: require('whatimdoing.JPG'),
    occurance: '',
    habitat: '',
    diet: '',
    reproduction: '',
    conservationStatus: '',
    funFactOne: ''
}
];
```

For now it works only when I'm on the animals card page and click the button, so the ID is present. If I'm somewhere else on the page and my ID is not declared yet, I receive an error that the data I want to display is undefined, which makes sense obviously. I've tried wrapping the return of the AnimalsDetails to log an error if the ID is not present but it didn't work.

I know there is some decent way to do that (probably with props or hooks defined differently), but I really tried many stuff and I'm utterly lost now. I wish I could pass the data to AnimalsDetails within clicking the button or something but have no idea how to do that. :-(

I'll be grateful for any help. I know it's basic stuff, but it's my first website ever.

Answer (score 2):

I understand your problems.
In my opinion you 'd like to focus useEffect method as below.

```
useEffect(() => {
 if(id != undefined)
    // console.log('error);
     return (
       <div>{'error'}</div>
     );
    const mammal = mammalsData.filter(thisMammal => thisMammal.id === id);
    setMammal(mammal);
    // console.log(mammal[0].animal);
 }, [id]);
```

Answer (score 1):

when you want to pass your data with url, in the `react router v6` has that capability.

Let say this is your Animals component,

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

//let assume this is the data that you need to send
const elephant = {
  animal: "Słoń indyjski",
  id: "slon_indyjski",
  species: "mammals",
  img: require("../../../images/animals/mammals/elephant.jpg"),
  occurance: "",
  habitat: "",
  diet: "",
  reproduction: "",
  conservationStatus: "",
  funFactOne: "",
};

const Animals = props => {
  //elephant.id is dynamic value. You have to add that value dynamically.
  return (
    <Link to={`${elephant.id}`} state={{ singleAnimal: elephant }}>
      <div>this is single animal</div>
    </Link>
  );
};
```

In the `Link component` you have to mention your `dynamic route` and you cant send your data from  `state` attribute.

In the receiving end,(Let say your receiving end component is `SingleanimalData`.

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
const SingleanimalData = props => {
  const location = useLocation();
  //animal variable now has that recieving data.so console it to view data
  const animal = location.state.singleAnimal;

  return (
    <div>
      <div>My animal name:</div>
      <div> {animal.animal} </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In here you have to use `useLocation` hook to grab data. I hope you this make sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.
In the parent component add this part

```
<Route path="/:id"  render={()=> <AnimalsDetails item={...animaldata} />} />
```

In AnimalDetails component

```
    import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
    import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
    
   const { animalId  } = useParams();
     
    let animal;
    useEffect(()=> {
      
   
    if(animalId && props.item) {
       animal = props.item.filter(a => a.id === animalId)
    }
    
    
    }, [animalId]);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Unfortunately I'm not sure where to pass myProps in this case. I've changed my AnimalsCard to obtain the whole data set (export const AnimalsCard = ({ data }) => {), but my button still only links to={`${data.id}`}. I don't think I can pass the props here.

Comment: You can get the dat afrom root element and then pass it as props.
I meant get the data in the component which contains this part
<Route path="/:id"  render={()=> <AnimalsDetails  item={...animaldata} />} />
Then inside AnimalDetails, filter the animalId inside useEffect with the relavent id

Comment: I updated my answer, please have a look on it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest react router (v6), use `element` instead of `render` ([here](https://dev.to/gabrlcj/react-router-v6-some-of-the-new-changes-181m)):

```
<Route path="/:id"  element={<AnimalsDetails animal={yourAnimal} />} />
```

Comment: Thank your for answering! I might update the react router, but I'm still not sure how to pass the animal object here. I guess it's not enough that I click the button on a page where my component is using the {animal} I've passed to it before. This is the crucial thing I don't understand:/

Comment: The last time I'm passing the animal object is in my AnimalGallery component:  <AnimalsCard {data={elephant}/> (I've changed that so I can pass all the attributes to the Route). Then, the data is used in the AnimalsCard - I don't know how to pass it from there to one more component. I hope I've made it clear somehow.